# Sending floats in a struct through Serial splits one of the values in half?

Tags: c++, struct, arduino

I need to send a struct of 6 float values through serial communication to a computer. Here is how my struct is defined:

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) data{
    float V_X;
    float V_Y;
    float V_Z;
    float R_X;
    float R_Y;
    float R_Z;
};

void sendData(float v_X, float v_Y, float v_Z, float r_X, float r_Y, float r_Z) {
    struct data packet = {v_X, v_Y, v_Z, r_X, r_Y, r_Z};
    Serial.write((byte*)&packet, sizeof(packet));
}
```

Calling `sendData` as follows:

```
float V_X = 12.3f;
float V_Y = 23.4f;
float V_Z = 34.5f;
float R_X = 45.6f;
float R_Y = 56.7f;
float R_Z = 67.8f;

sendData(V_X, V_Y, V_Z, R_X, R_Y, R_Z);
```

I capture the output with Putty, and I get this: `ÍÌDA33»A Bff6BÍÌbBš™‡B` or

`CD CC 44 41 33 33 BB 41 0A 42 66 66 36 42 CD CC 62 42 9A 99 87 42 0D 0A`

Which plugged into a hex editor, confirms that the first and second 4-byte floats are correct. After that however, bytes 9 and 10 are junk, followed by 12 more correct bytes which give us the last 3 floats. Finally we have 2 more bytes. Reconstructing bytes 24, 23, 10 and 9, in that order, does in fact give us the value we want - 34.5. But why is this particular float being split in half?

Comment: If your application relies on the way those floats are represented in memory, you should manually serialize that data. The solution you will find by fiddling like that will break as soon as you will change compiler, OS, or who knows... sweatshirt.

Comment: That does make sense, but even still, it doesn't explain why a single float is being split in half. All 4 bytes of a float are stored in series in memory, right?

Comment: make sure you've set serial settings same at both receiver and sender side.

Comment: 34.5f should be `00 00 0a 42` but only `0a 42` got through.  The additional two bytes look like **CR LF** to me `0D 0A` (added by putty?) though that may be a coincidence.  Begin by looking at the 24 bytes *before* you send them so you know what to expect, then make sure your serial settings are good, so Putty isn't translating something, for example.

Comment: Serial is a stream based interface. Don't expect to read the same chunks that you send. i.e. if you send "abcd" you might receive "ab" and then "cd" or if you send "ab" and then "cd", you might receive "abc" and then "d". And a program to deal with textual data isn't the right tool to debug binary data.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I couldn't figure out why my data was getting garbled. Instead, as per users YSC and gre_gor's suggestions, I did away with the struct, and instead sent out each float separately, in order and with a leading start-byte for parsing. This manual serialization worked.